# IBM Watson text-to-speech command returns bad request code: 400

Tags: curl, ibm-watson

i tried running the following command :

```
    curl -X POST -u "username":"password" 
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" 
        --header "Accept: audio/wav" 
        --data '{"text": "hello world"}' 
        --output hello_world.wav 
        "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize"
```

The output with no .wav file generated:

```
    curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 12
{
   "code_description": "Bad Request",
   "code": 400,
   "error": "No JSON object could be decoded"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the json, so I guess that you are on windows, where `'` don't work with curl. You are going to have to use `"` and either escape the `"` within the json or use a .json file.

```
--data "{\"text\":\"Hello world\"}"
```